# Read pmml model object in R

Tags: r, xml, arules, pmml

I'm trying to use the `arules` package to read a PMML random forest model object and predict using it. Below is what I have using the iris dataset as an example. I'm getting an error when I try to read the PMML that says `File does not contain an AssociationModel.` Is it possible to read in a model object using the     arules or some other package?

```
library(arules)
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
rf <- randomForest(Species~., data=iris, ntree=10)
write.PMML(rf, 'irisrf.pmml')
irisrf <- read.PMML('irisrf.pmml')
#This is where I get the error
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718468/can-pmml-models-be-read-in-r

Comment: I saw that. Based on JobJob's comment I thought maybe there was a way to read in PMML model objects using `arules`.

Comment: With `read.PMM` you can only read `arules` objects saved in `pmml` format.

Comment: I changed the save to .pmml but still have the same problem.